# How can I import module from another folder which is not same directory structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have two directory on same level

```
1.Scripts->(Inside it we have app.py file)
2. Keymaker-->(Inside it we have keymaker.py file)
```

Now I want to import keymaker.py in app.py, So how Can I do it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score -1):

Write these lines in app.py file.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/Keymaker/dir')
```

After that you can import anything from keymaker.py file using
`from keymaker import *`

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Add empty `__init__.py` file to Keymaker directory and do `from Keymaker import keymaker`